# How can I compare an array of timestamps from firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, timestamp

I am trying to compare the array filled with timestamps from multiple devices when they press a button. Then from the main host app, there I want to fetch all the timestamps and store them in the above mentioned array and tell who was the first to press the button.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and then come back with the following information (at least): What did you try so far? Can you show any code that helps us understand what you've did or are trying to do? What prevents you from making progress, i.e. what exactly are you struggling with?

Answer (score 0):

I would say in you app get the time stamp value and compare it to your comparison value. If it passes your criteria upload it. For timestamps I would recommend calendar (API). Set the values to strings and compare the strings. Then loop for all your data.